# quicksort with linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, quicksort

i have wrote  code for    quicksort with linked list ,here is code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct _tagIntegerList
{
    int  nInteger;
    struct _tagIntegerList *prev;
    struct _tagIntegerList *next;


}IntegerList;
IntegerList *firstitem=NULL;
IntegerList *lastitem=NULL;
void addlist(int n)
{

IntegerList *pitem=new IntegerList;
pitem->nInteger=n;
if ( firstitem==NULL){
firstitem=lastitem=pitem;
pitem->next=pitem->prev=NULL;

}
else{
    lastitem->next=pitem;
    pitem->prev=lastitem;
    lastitem=pitem;
    pitem->next=NULL;


}




}
void removeall(){
    IntegerList *delitem,*pitem=firstitem;
    while(pitem!=NULL){
        delitem=pitem;
        pitem=pitem->next;
        delete delitem;



    }

    firstitem=lastitem=NULL;
}


void print(){

    IntegerList * pitem=firstitem;
    while(pitem!=NULL){

        cout<<pitem->nInteger<<" ";
        pitem=pitem->next;


    }

}
// Quick Sort List
void quicksort(IntegerList *left, IntegerList *right)
{
    IntegerList *start;
    IntegerList *current;
    int copyinteger;

    if (left==right) return ;
    start=left;
    current=start->next;
    while(1){
        if (start->nInteger<current->nInteger){
            copyinteger=current->nInteger;
            current->nInteger=start->nInteger;
        start->nInteger=copyinteger;


        }
// Check if we have reached the right end
        if (current=right) break;
        current=current->next;






    }



    //swap first and current items
    copyinteger=left->nInteger;
    left->nInteger=current->nInteger;
    current->nInteger=copyinteger;
        IntegerList *oldcurrent=current;
        // Check if we need to sort the left hand size of the Current point
        current=current->prev;
        if (current!=NULL){
            if ((left->prev!=current)&& (current->next!=left))
                quicksort(left,current);
                }
current=oldcurrent;
current=current->next;
if (current!=NULL){

    if ((current->prev!=right)&& (right->next!=current))
        quicksort(current,right);

}
}
int main(){
    addlist(100);
    addlist(12);
    addlist(56);
    addlist(67);
    addlist(4);
    addlist(91);
    addlist(34);
    addlist(59);
    addlist(42);
    addlist(20);
    addlist(83);
    addlist(74);
    addlist(33);
    addlist(79);
    addlist(49);
    addlist(51);

    quicksort(firstitem,lastitem);
    print();
    removeall();
 return 0;
}
```

but  output is not what i am expecting,here is result

```
4 56 67 12 91 34 59 42 20 83 74 33 79 49 51 100
```

please help me what is wrong  with this code?and also i am interested complexity  of algorithm  is it  same O(nlogn)?

Comment: Quicksort is not appropriate for linked lists. Quicksort works when you have fast random access. For a linked list, quicksort is not O(n log n). What you need is merge sort.

Comment: Please try improving the presentation of you code to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: Vote to close: rather than asking strangers to spot the error by staring at your code, you should investigate the problem with the debugger.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I initially removed the C++ tag, as this is a C question (still is): C++ is only 'used' to print some stuff to the screen (for which printf() could also have been used). The real code uses a struct (which might look like a class due the th used naming) and some other 'C stuff'. But I'll leave the C++ tag, as I do not want to start a 'tagging-war'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `current=right` should be `current==right`
in `if (current=right) break;`

Comment: i have found it,thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

and then I suggest, rather than implementing algorithms and data structure by yourself, try to familiarize with STL.

Lists and sorting algorithm are well-implemented.

Comment: @DanielFischer why would the C++ tag be gone? While the code smells like C, there are a couple of `cout <<...` that make it very much C++ (`#include<iostream>`, `using namespace std`...)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Ah, it reappeared, now the C tag is gone. Originally, the question was tagged both, then the C++ tag was removed, now it's tagged only C++. Considering the use of `<iostream>` and `cout`, appropriately. Sorry for the noise.